# Any recommendations for a domain buying negotiating service?

Tags: domains

The best domain for my niche and related is owned by a guy in San Fransisco, and I want to buy the domain from him but I don't want to deal with him directly (even though he has contacted me in the past).

I need to find an intermediary company that can handle the negotiation for me. I don't expect to have to pay much since the guy has been squatting on it for more than 15 years and according to the Internet Wayback Machine it has never actually been used for anything at all - he has never added any value to it. It kind of irritates me that such a good domain has been sitting in this guy's closet gather dust for 15 years.

I know that GoDaddy has a domain buying negotiating service (and the domain is registered through them, which may make it easier), but I really, really do not want to do business with GoDaddy if I don't have too.

Do any of you know of other firms that deal with this sort of thing?

Comment: If it irritates you that this sort of thing happens, then buy a different domain name that is actually available instead of supporting domain squatters. Otherwise, it's like saying you hate spam, but then clicking on a spam email and making a purchase when it's such purchases that encourage spammers to spam.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would rather deal directly with an individual for transactions like this whenever possible, especially if the other person has tried contacting you already.

Any middle-man company is going to want to take either a standard fee for this, or even a percentage of the amount of the transaction. Even if it is the seller that would cover these costs it is likely he would just pass those costs on to you when determining the price to sell the domain.

It doesn't make much difference that the domain has never been used in this case. While traffic and users do increase a site's value, it doesn't mean the owner of an unused domain will base their price solely on these values. If the owner keeps renewing the domain there is no way you can get it. You are basically stuck at whatever price the other person wants for it. There is no service that can get a domain from someone for cheap because they don't use it. The sale would have to be on terms agreed to by the buyer and seller.

Also, you may be able to use PayPal to conduct the transaction, as it may qualify for "buyer protection" if something happens and the domain doesn't get transferred to you after paying. Also, if you use a credit card as your PayPal payment source you could also get the credit card company to reverse the charges.

I am currently in the same position as you, as there is an unused domain that I would like, but I cannot contact the owner as the WHOIS information is not correct.